# Using REGEX to get a sanitized string (not check whether it fits the regex)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have used `preg_match` to check whether a string matches a given regular expression, but not to parse out the invalid characters. This is what I want to do, in a function named `toSearchableString($string)`:

Passed original string: `Where'd You Go (feat. Holly Brook and Jonah Matranga)`

Returned sanitized string: `Whered You Go feat Holly Brook and Jonah Matranga`

If we have to replace the characters that are invalid with anything, a space is preferred (or an empty string to simply remove them).

This is the REGEX I want it matched against: `a-zA-Z0-9` and a space

Thanks!

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a pattern that matches invalid characters as the first argument, an empty string as the second argument, and your original string as the third argument.

Comment: Is there any way to match the valid characters? I know what REGEX to use to match the valid, but I dont want to possibly forget some characters to exclude (and end with unsanitized strings)

Comment: @NicholasYost - It shouldn't be difficult to negate your regex, if your valid characters are `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`, then `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` will match all characters *except* for the valid ones.

Comment: - Thank you for everything. I was forgetting the slashes around the REGEX, and once I realized they were needed, everything came together. This is the final code I ended up with: $sanitized = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+/', '', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Have fun with this : 
http://www.txt2re.com/index-php.php3

I'm using it since a lot of time, I still do not know how to code regex by myself, lazily. This helps a lot and you can tweak a bit the code after to make what you want with it.

Just saying, this help a lot sometimes.

Comment: I havent been able to figure that site out. I found it yesterday when trying to solve this then, but couldn't figure out what I needed to click after I pasted the string and clicked the "Show Matches" button.

I also found http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but couldn't figure that one out either.